# How can I replace string in a list with python?

Tags: python, replace, web-scraping

I want to change all these : '/' to this : ' / ' and looking for the value before the / and insert a space character.
(So iv got this : '8/3' and i want this : ' 8 / 3 ')
This is my code:

```js
datatable=[]
stop = 0
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" ):
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if '/' in data.text:
                record2 = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')
                final_format = ' {} '.format(record2)
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                stop = 1
                break
        datatable.append(temp_data)
        if stop == 1:
            break
    if stop == 1:
        break
output.writerows(datatable)
```

How can i reach it?

Comment: Strings are immutable. `record.replace` isn't doing anything, but your error seems to indicate that `record` is set to None

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but even `record.replace`works you are not storing it anywhere or using it afterwards so the line basically does nothing to affect the outcome of the code. Maybe it is easier if you just get your data from the soup and then in a different loop correct it.

Comment: i edited my question, i have to use "data.text.replace" and it is working, but i want to reach this format: '8/3' -- > ' 8 / 3 '

Comment: @tardos93 strings are immutable you have to do `data2 - data.text.replace('/', ' / ')`

Answer (score 2):

the `find_all` function from `bs4` is not returning strings but bs tags, you need to convert record to string in order to use the replace method.

```
useful_string = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')
```

is the way to go.

Comment: You also need to make sure to do `record2 = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')` cause strings are immutable so you need to put them into a new variable

Comment: done, thanks for the advice,  if he wants to store the actual value, that is the way to go

Comment: it is working, thank you! But the second part of my question?
I have this value '8/3' and i want this : ' 8 / 3 ' (i have to insert a space before the 8, because if i open it in csv i get a data format.)

Comment: this is not a very pretty way to do it, but if you can isolate the values like 8/3, you can use string format like: `final_format = ' {} '.format(useful_string)`

Comment: i updated my code, but it isnt working, i get the same bad result.